# Is there a mathematical system that is: complete, consistent, and decidable?

Tags: incompleteness, modal-logic, meta-math

I know very little about modal logic (only some set theory) in mathematics, but I am aware that there exists a completeness theorem, incompleteness theorem, and the axiom choice, and that maths is not always decidable.

However, my interest in modal logic has been growing and I started wondering **if there was a way for some system of mathematics to be all: complete, consistent, and decidable, while being most similar to current mathematics.** The closest thing I've seen is Presburger arithmetic, but I believe it does not have the Axiom of Infinity.

**Could someone tell me if there is or isn't and provide a reasonably clear justification for the answer?** I do not mind if you use logic symbols that you think I may not understand, but it would be appreciated if you added a comment next to them to explain what they mean.

Comment: Do you know about propositional logic?

Comment: You mention that you're aware of [Godel's incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_incompleteness_theorems). Can you clarify how that theorem does not answer your question?

Comment: The Presburger arithmetic is complete and consistent. It is also not a finite theory.

Comment: @Karl It doesn't answer the question since there are weaker forms of arithmetic that aren't able to model the naturals to the sufficient power required for GIT, and thus aren't subject to its result.

Comment: @kubo I would guess that I understand most of the propositional logic symbols and the statements made using them, from the online research that I have occasionally done.

Comment: @RushabhMehta I still think the clarification I asked for would help us understand the OP's background and precise question. Those weaker forms of arithmetic might not be considered "similar to current mathematics" enough. The question is vague.

Comment: @Karl In fact, the Presburger arithmetic is too weak to define what a prime number is.

Comment: @RushabhMehta as I have said before, I do not know much about modal logic, and I incompleteness theorem means that no mathematical system has true statements that are all provable. I should have made it more clear that I was hopeful there were some advancements in logic that may have changed things up. Really any answer at all will help me.

Comment: @AndreiMurashev Then I'm afraid that this question isn't answerable at this point. Hold this question until you have a better understanding of model theory.

Comment: @AndreiMurashev As already mentioned, Goedel's incompleteness theorems specify that the theory must be powerful enough that the representation theorem holds in it. This is the case in particular, if it contains the peano axioms (PA). Such a theory cannot be BOTH complete and consistent. It must be either incomplete or inconsistent.  For weaker theories, both Goedel incompleteness theorems do not hold in general.

Comment: @Peter thank you. I like this answer.